# how to import data from sql to excel and update sql data

Tags: sql

for me user interface is excel sheet. so i want functionality such that i can import data from sql table.

and when i update data in excell sheet it shoul be update in sql table also.

can any one give me solution??

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions have been asked. See this:

[Two-Way Excel to SQL Connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/568808/is-an-ms-sql-excel-connection-two-way)

MS Access is a more appropriate tool for SQL Server connections, but if you have to use Excel then follow those links.

Hope that helps!